# Bad model deploying to GCP Cloudml

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I’m trying to deploy a model trained using Tensorflow 1.7 onto Google Cloud Platform. I get the following error:

Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: Op type not registered 'SparseFillEmptyRows'\n\n (Error code: 0)"

I know Cloudml runtime prediction only supports Tensorflow 1.6 so I tried specifying:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
  'tensorflow==1.6',
]
```

in setup.py but I still get the same message

Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: So you want to use Tensorflow 1.7 and you're setting the version to 1.6 in your setup file ? Anyway...it looks like you're having a problem elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your model using TensorFlow 1.6. You can't deploy a model created with TensorFlow 1.7 to the ML Engine.

Also, you can set the version of the engine's runtime to one of the versions listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list). If you're using `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`, you can set the version with the `--runtime-version` flag. The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training).

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding with 1.6 and deploying with --runtime-version=1.6 worked.